# Async function returns ZoneAwarePromise in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I have function `currentUserName()` that should return `name` but returns ZoneAwarePromise containing __zone_symbol__value with right data.

```
currentUserName() {
        var firebaseData = firebase.database().ref('users');
        var userid = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;

        return firebaseData.orderByKey().once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
            var name;
            snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
                if (childSnapshot.key === userid) {
                    name = childSnapshot.val().displayName;
                }
            });
            return name;
        });
    }
```

Function call:

```
this.currentUserName().then(function (snapshot) { return snapshot; }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a promise?

```
currentUserName(): Promise<any> {
        var firebaseData = firebase.database().ref('users');
        var userid = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;

        return firebaseData.orderByKey().once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
            var name;
            snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
                if (childSnapshot.key === userid) {
                    name = childSnapshot.val().displayName;
                }
            });

            return name;

}
```

and call it like this

```
this.currentUserName().then(function(name) { console.log(name) }));
```

Comment: try to log the result of firebase if it returns a data inside your `forEach`

Comment: yes, it returns right data, if I log it before resolve. But in console it shows after zoneawarepromise.

Comment: but what I understand, you're aiming to get the name of the current active user? if thats the case why not subscribe to `this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => console.log(user))`

Comment: The problem is that authstate doesn't know about name. It knows about email, password and uid.